# Historical data components of S&P 1500

Tags: data, historical

I am doing some research about market microstructure and for this reason I need the historical data of stock symbols included in the S&P 1500 Composite Index. Namely, I need to know which stock symbols were part of the index in the past. Do you know where I can retrieve this? (Free) Data about the past 5 years would suffice, I am in academia so I have academic access to some data providers. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have access to WRDS? Would S&P 500 members suffice?

Answer (score 0):

if your university has bloomberg you could pull the members and their weights.

Comment: Unfortunately we don’t have it

Comment: maybe openbb? it used to be for free.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that you can get this for free. If you can live with a smaller universe like [S&P 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies) or [600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_600_companies) then you can get the current constituents plus historical changes from Wikipedia. It will require a bit of effort to parse the changes into a useable format but it looks doable. This assumes you don't need the weights, although you could probably proxy them using historical market caps.

If you're a Python user then you can leverage a package like [BeautifulSoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) to programmatically access the tables and store them in a more friendly data structure.